# Getting started with calling APIs via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xml, api, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I've just started to learn how to use APIs, but I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding exactly how to utilize them.

I was able to write the following code thanks to some online documentation, but I have some questions about how to add to it:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=xml", false); xhr.send(); 
console.log(xhr);
```

Now, when I run this code in my browser and I open the console, I get a dropdown with a whole bunch of stuff under it.  First of all, how can I get the code to display JUST the response?  I want the console to display just the XML to show when I run my code.  Second of all, how do I parse the XML?  Is there any way to get a value from an XML element and assign it to a JavaScript variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use *A*jax from the beginning, not using synchronous requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are printing is the XMLHttpRequest object itself, while what you actually want is the response from the request you've made. To get the response, you use

```
xhr.responseXML;
```

Which is a object of the type `document`. (See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties)).

To exhibit the code, you can just

```
console.log(xhr.responseXML);
```

But to actually work with the response, you'll probably want to do as Josh suggested, and request from the API a JSON-formatted response (instead of a XML-formatted one).

You will probably want to do that asyncronously, too (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)). The page has a more robust example. Let's adapt it to show London's temperature:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=json", true);
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      console.log("Temperature(K): " + response.main.temp);
    } else {
      console.error(xhr.statusText);
    }
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
  console.error(xhr.statusText);
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Being async means that the xhr.onLoad function will be executed as soon as the response is received. Thus all of your code will be executed sequentially, and only when the response is received the onLoad will be executed.

Comment: Thanks!  All the responses were very helpful but this one was the most informative.

Comment: I think it would be better if, this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 for readability

Answer (score 1):

That dropdown is probably your browser formatting the response object in an interactive way for you.

`xmlDoc=xhr.responseXML;` will give you the actual resulting text

**Alternatively:** you could request a JSON object to make working with the data much easier.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=json", false); xhr.send(); 
var data= JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); //data is now a javascript object full of the API data
```

Note how the url now reads `mode=json` now.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the response as a [Document object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML).

Using your code above, you can reference `xhr.responseXML` and use the [Document documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document) to learn how to grab what data you need.